# System process hogging disk, can't find why

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, monitoring

Recenty I have noticed my hard drive activity unusually increased, to the point the system is sometimes bogged down.

Using resource monitor, it shows the system process writing constantly to a file on the hard disk.

As an Administrator I am unable to see which file. I tried to use the Sysinternals handle tool but don't have permission.

How can I track down this strange disk activity?

OS is windows server 2008 r2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the Windows Server 2008 R2 resource monitor.

Run perfmom.exe and select Open Resource Monitor, go to the tab called Disk, and check the section called Disk Activity. 
There you can order by Read and Write bytes per second and one of the colums of that table is the file which are being accessed.

Regards.